# How to check whether human is straight looking or not using Java with opencv

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I'm using java with opencv,javacv for an image processing project. The image is not taking from the camera. I'm giving the image as below.

```
Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread("E:/resources/PPHOTOO/test.jpg");
```

and using haarcascades I'm cropping the face image too.

```
CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier("C:\\opencv\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");

String faces;
MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
Mat face;
Mat crop = null;

 for (int i = 0; i< faceDetections.toArray().length; i++){

            faces = "Face"+i+".png";

             face = image.submat(faceDetections.toArray()[i]);
             crop = face.submat(4, (2*face.width())/3, 0, face.height());
            Imgcodecs.imwrite(faces, face);
}
```

I want to find whether person is person is straight looking or not. Which means not side faces. I need to know how to find this part.

[straight looking image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYKhW.png)

[side face image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXqJp.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [ask]. You have to ask a question in order to get an answer. Just formulating an overly broad topic will get you downvoted and closed quickly. Pleae improve your post.

Comment: @Piglet  noted. Thanks :)